# Slick 3 dynamic groupby - fields from its List[String]

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, slick-3.0

Lets say i want to execute the query:

```
select columnName1,columnName2,Sum(*)
from table
group by columnName1,columnName2
```

where columnName1,columnName2 is supplied from list[string] ("columnName1",columnName2")

how can i do it with slick?
if the columns are known by compile time, i can easily use the groupBy function:

```
tableQuery.groupBy { r => (r.columnName1,r.columnName2)}.map (case groupName,group) => (groupName._1,groupName._2,group.map(...).avg)}
```

but what about dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `r.column("foo")` syntax to access columns dynamically at runtime, so I believe you can just do something like the following?

```
columnNames = List("col1", "col2")
tableQuery
    .groupBy(r => columnNames.map(name => r.column(name)))
    .map({ case (groupName, group) => /* do something with it */})
```

Comment: in slick 3.2.3, using a collection of columnNames results: `Slick does not know how to map the given types.`

Answer (score 0):

To convert a string column name to Rep type, you can use the [Slick AST Library](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/api/index.html#slick.ast.Library$).
I had a similar requirement and done it using the `AST Library`. 
You can refer to [this code](https://github.com/thenewmotion/scala-kendoui/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/thenewmotion/kendoui/SlickQuery.scala), which does the same thing. I also followed the same code to solve my requirement.